# How to connect Reused Reducers Logic into React components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using the pattern described [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html) that show us how to reuse reducer logic for other similar purposes.

So, my reducer code is like the code below:

```
function ContentFilterReducer(entity = ''){
    initialState.groupFilter = entity;
    return function ContentFilterReducer(state = initialState, action)
    {

        // is the entity that we want to update?
        if (action.item !== undefined && action.item.groupFilter !== entity)
            return state;

        switch (action.type) {
            case ContentFilterTypes.ADD_ITEM:
                return {
                    // we set the 
                    groupFilter: action.item.groupFilter,
                    listObjects : state.listObjects.push(new Map({
                        id: action.item.id,
                        description: action.item.description,
                        imgSrc: action.item.imgSrc
                    }))
                } 

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}
```

My **combinedReducer** describe a reducer for each purpose, as we can see below:

```
const SearchReducers = combineReducers({
    // contains all allowed filters to be selected
    UsersContentFilterReducer : ContentFilterReducer(Types.users),
    OrganizationsContentFilterReducer : ContentFilterReducer(Types.organizations)

})
```

Everything is working great, however I'd like to know, how to connect it in a React component using the **connect** function from **React-Redux**?

As we can see, I can define the reducer setting an **entity** (a simple char like 'a', 'o', etc) and, to call the specific reducer, I need only set the **entity** in my action. And now, the problem is how to **connect** a specific reducer for a specific presentational component?

The code below is my HOC container that connect the reducer to a specific component, however, the code is the old version, without defining wich reducer should call.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, action) => {
    return {
        contentList: ContentFilterReducer(state.ContentFilterReducer, action)
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {contains the action that will be dispatched} dispatch 
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onAddClick: (groupFilter, filterDescription, operator, value) => {
            dispatch(AddFilter(groupFilter, filterDescription, operator, value));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentFilterField)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *connect a reducer*. You connect a **component** to the Redux **store**. I won't name my state `xxxReducer`, it's a little bit confusing.

I'm not sure what your app looks like, for a simple case, you just need to: (connect both state)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userContentList: state.SearchReducers.UsersContentFilterReducer,
    organizationContentList: state.SearchReducers.OrganizationsContentFilterReducer,
  }
}
```

If you want to switch between `usersContent` and `organizationsContent` dynamically based on your component's state, what you need is a `selector` function.

This is the official redux example: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/reducers/index.js#L10-L26

These functions are selectors, you import and use them to get the state you want.

So you will create something like `getContentList` and it accepts a `type` like `Types.users`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // suppose you save current type saved in SearchReducers.type
    contentList: getContentList(state.SearchReducers.type)
  }
}
```

Also, the second parameter of `mapStateToProps` is `ownProps` not `action`.